# How to use margin:0 auto in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to center align a `div` on click, but this is not working

```
$().click(function(){
    $(".scale_roll").css({"width" : "80% ","margin":"0 auto"});
});
```

When I used `marign-left`:`100px` it works fine. What is the problem in aligning the div to center using this property in jQuery?

Comment: In your code it's `"auto 0"` not `"0 auto"`, that may be the problem

Comment: `auto 0` should be `0 auto`;

Comment: You have incorrect `cllick`, it should be `click`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TYPO.

`auto 0` should be `0 auto`:

```
$(".scale_roll").css({"width" : "80% ","margin":"0 auto"});
```

Comment: I used 0 auto but this case also not align the centre of the div.

Comment: @Khaja: can you share the relevant html along with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Your target in click function is empty, it should be something like this:

```
$(".scale_roll").click( function() {
    $(this).css({
        "width": "80%",
        "margin": "0 auto"
    });
});
```

working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n51wm78w/)

Answer (score 0):

Move div to the center and then back to its original position. Please click "*Run code snippet*" below

```js
$(".scale_roll").click(function(){
   if($(this).width() == 100)
       $(this).css({"width" : "80% ","margin":"0 auto"});
   else
       $(this).css({"width" : "100px ","margin":"0"});
});
```

```css
.scale_roll{
  width:100px; 
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scale_roll">Click Me<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not spelled your `click` function correctly.

```
$().click(function(){
$(".scale_roll").css({"width" : "80% ","margin":"0 auto"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess instead of giving `"margin":"0 auto"` you can give `"margin":"auto"`.

```
$(".scale_roll").click( function() {
    $(this).css({
        "width": "80%",
           "margin": "auto"
    });
});
```

This my working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gLn9z365/)